# Cannot install / setup the Open VPN in Ubuntu Mate 15.10

Tags: vpn

I am a new user of Ubuntu,i was using windows for so long but really dont miss it but i am having issues trying to install / setup the open vpn ...
I get this in the mate terminal when i try to install it:

To run a command as administrator (user "root"), use "sudo ".
See "man sudo_root" for details. (dont know what is sudo)

andrews@andrews-Satellite-C645D:~$ sudo apt-get install openvpn
[sudo] password for andrews: (get stuck in here,cannot type my password)

Here is the manual to set up the vpn i did buy :

https://nordvpn.com/tutorials/linux/openvpn/ 
https://nordvpn.com/tutorials/linux/pptp/

When i try to type my password,there is no way to do it ...i need your help please cause i really dont want to go back to windows,i did fall in love immediately with Ubuntu !!!

Answer (score 0):

It's for Security purposes you will be not able to see anything when you are typing your password, so that others can't guess your password by looking at number of characters or so...

You just type your Password and type enter.

`sudo` is command you use to give it another command a higher level privileges,Incase of windows you 'run it as Administrator'.

You are supposed to give root privileges in order to install any package (Application).

Comment: Hi.Thanks for your help !!!! it works (the issue about the password) now the problem is that i can't make it works (the vpn)...there is an easy or at least a way to make this works ??? can someone guide me through the process ??? the manual from NordVPN doesn't works ...and got another issue too ...i did try to encrypt the hard disk but i dont know if i did the wrong security key for the hard disk encryption...any ideas on how to make a good security key to encrypt the hard disk ??? i think Ubuntu should use Tor browser by default instead of Mozilla so we got no issues adding the open vpn

Comment: No you show me the output error of installing vpn, you should have used >http://www.vpnbook.com/ because it is free of cost, encrypting hard-drive in Linux doesn't need any password to access it encrpyt's the hard-drive in such a way that, you can't open any folder,if you have two Os's or from a live USB.